# How to start wamp?

Tags: php, wamp

I am unable to start wamp, .pid file deleted from location wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\data, because of which unable to connect phpmyadmin, it's showing 2002 error, Please guide about how to start wamp.

Comment: `pid file deleted from location ...` , then download new one from internet. And use it . Else go for XAMPP.

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow; it's more appropriate for SuperUser, perhaps. StackOverflow is for programming-related questions.

Comment: Was your installation without errors? Did you see the wamp icon in the list.? If not you have to download a new wamp from internet or else download xampp.

Comment: Yes, I installed wamp successfully, but by mistakely .pid file deleted by me due to which unable to connect to phpmyadmin, which consist of very importatnt data, and i want to recover it.. Please guide me how to do it.  Now it showing orange icon only.

Answer (score 0):

The .pid file is recreated each time MySQL starts.

Mine looks like `wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\data\MACHINE_NAME.pid`

Deleting it should not cause MySQL to fail on restart, so there must be another problem. Look at the `mysql error log` and if that does not tell you anything useful, look at the `Windows Event Viewer`, MySQL writes to the event viewer even before it tries to open and use its error.log file. There may be something in there that tells you what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the Control Panel of the system and then remove the wamp server after you choose a new wamp server.